# Are questions about issues with the output of a sound generation program on topic?

Tags: discussion, topic-scope

[This question](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/29944/sine-wave-making-no-sound) recently asked what was wrong with the audio file being generated by a program that was supposed to produce a sound wave.  The purpose of the question seems to be to figure out why the sampled sound doesn't work as expected, however, it still feels to me like it is more a programming question than having anything to do with the core of Sound Design.

Do we want questions like this to be on topic?

Answer (score 5):

I think even questions that are quite involved programming-wise can be on topic here, as long *the immediate problem* is about audio: why do I hear this artifact here, why is this not audible, what parameter should I use for this codec etc.. There is certainly some overlap with [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) and in particular [DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/), but sound design experts ought to be best at identifying technical problems *by ear* (or audio tool) as well as knowing the precise consequences of particular signal processing techniques and standard effects or codecs.

Questions about technical details which are common to other programming / DSP applications, like how to perform general file IO, how or when to implement a given mathematical transformation etc. should of course not be on topic here.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this should be on-topic.  It is really a programming question.  Sure the output isn't sounding like they expect, but it is a debugging issue.  If it was truly a sine wave of appropriate frequency, then the audio would be audible when played back.  It is either a problem in the wave function or a problem in the way the audio file is being written.  Either way, it is a programming bug and finding it is not related to Sound Design or even Audio Production in any meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

I am in agreement with leftaround in that there is some overlap here.  While the question certainly does seem like a programming issue, the OP is using a fairly common audio editing tool - sox - that I myself use for sound design.  I would feel that operational questions about it could be on topic.  I don't think the OP would find a more appropriate answer in another forum as his question is specific to the tool and its uses.